# Android Studio : "Unable to locate adb"

Tags: sdk, adb, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-4.0, platform-tools

I just installed Android Studios and trying to build my first app. When I press play on the emulator the message "unable to locate adb" pop-up. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studios error : Unable to locate adb location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234109/android-studios-error-unable-to-locate-adb-location)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem when updating to Android Studio 4.0.
I even tried uninstalling (and doing a full cleanup) Android Studio and installing again. The problem persisted.
The problem was that when importing my old project, the new Android Studio couldn't find the SDK and my project had no SDK (even though it could build, go figure).
So check `File -> Project Structure -> Project`. In my case there was a big red NO SDK set there. Once I set the SDK to the one installed, problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't set the system and user environment path in your windows.

Goto properties of This PC > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Path > then put the path file location.

Answer (score -1):

intel android driver setup install this after its worked for me

Comment: This is not an answer, please consider leaving a comment instead.

Comment: this error could happen by driver issues also, not only program issue.

Comment: might help anyone my user . don't tell blankly not answer